# Should I include gender dummy for the probit regression in Heckman?

Tags: stata, heckman, decomposition

I'm estimating the wage equation for a selected sample which contains both males and females, afterwards which will be decomposed using the Oaxaca command in stata, by gender.

The wage equation for the Oaxaca-Blinder Decomposition by gender doesn't contain a gender dummy.

However, I am also checking for sample selection bias, and so was wondering if the probit model which will be used to calculate the Inverse Mills Ratio (IMR) should include a gender dummy or not. This is because as mentioned earlier, the main equation doesn't have one.

N.B. The IMR calculation I'm interested in is for participation into the sample for both genders.